# Fusion table api migration

Tags: api, google-fusion-tables, google-api-java-client

I am using fusion table APIs to insert/update data in my table. Last week I migrated my API to new version v1 as referred in [this sample](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#Fusion_Tables_API). But now, when I run the code, the following error displayed.

```
400 Bad Request
{
  "error" : "unauthorized_client"
}
com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "error" : "unauthorized_client"
}
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException.from(TokenResponseException.java:105)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:303)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:323)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.executeRefreshToken(Credential.java:607)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:526)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.intercept(Credential.java:287)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:836)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:412)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:345)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:463)
    at com.prasanna.survey.pushapis.FusionPush.insertData(FusionPush.java:198)
    at com.prasanna.survey.pushapis.FusionPush.main(FusionPush.java:96)
Java Result: 1
```

How to debug this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error typically occurs if you change the client_id of an application.

The reason is, you already have an access token for the Fusion API that's based on the old client_id.  When you request a refresh token (as you can see is happening in the stack trace) with the new client_id, you get that very unhelpful error message.

The easiest way to handle this is to clear the existing credential from the system so it has to receive a clean access token. You can do this programatically with the Google API Java Client, or you can just remove the file from your system.  On my Ubuntu machine, it is located at `~/.credentials/<api-name>.json`.